# No such slot QLineEdit::setText

Tags: c++, qt

I'm trying to connect a push button to a lineEdit.when click on push button,set text of lineEdit to "Hello".
but i have a problem with signal and slot!

[This is my form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K92uR.png)

mainwindow.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    connect(ui->pushButton,SIGNAL(clicked()),ui->lineEdit,SLOT(setText("Hello")));
}
MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

mainwindow.h

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QLineEdit>
#include <QPushButton>
namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

Application output

```
Starting C:\Qt\Qt5.3.0\Tools\QtCreator\bin\build-E01S01-Desktop_Qt_5_3_0_MSVC2013_OpenGL_64bit-Debug\debug\E01S01.exe...
QObject::connect: No such slot QLineEdit::setText("Hello") in ..\E01S01\mainwindow.cpp:9
QObject::connect:  (sender name:   'pushButton')
QObject::connect:  (receiver name: 'lineEdit')
```

Comment: You can't add parameters in a connection. Fix this with QSignalMapper.

Comment: [Please read the documentation on Signals and Slots](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/signalsandslots.html) to understand why this doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can only connect a `SIGNAL` to a `SLOT` if they has the same signature.
You can use `QSignalMapper` to accomplish what you want:

```
QSignalMapper * mapper = new QSignalMapper(this);
QObject::connect(mapper, SIGNAL(mapped(const QString&)), ui->lineEdit, SLOT(setText(const QString&)));
QObject::connect(ui->pushButton, SIGNAL(clicked()), mapper, SLOT(map()));
mapper->setMapping(ui->pushButton, tr("Hello"));
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using Qt5, you can use a lambda expression.
First make sure `c++11` is enabled by adding `CONFIG += c++11` in your `.pro` file.

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QWidget>
#include <QLayout>
#include <QLineEdit>
#include <QPushButton>    

class Widget : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    Widget(QWidget *parent = 0) : QWidget(parent)
    {
        setLayout(new QVBoxLayout);
        QLineEdit *lineEdit = new QLineEdit("TEXT");
        QPushButton *button = new QPushButton("BUTTON");
        connect(button, &QPushButton::clicked, this, [=]{lineEdit->setText("PRESSED");});

        layout()->addWidget(lineEdit);
        layout()->addWidget(button);
    }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    Widget w;
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}

#include "main.moc"
```

Comment: Thanks for posting this answer.. I do not think of solutions like this because I am stuck (dependent library compatibility issues) having to support Qt4 on about 1/2 of my applications at work so for now even when I am developing in Qt5 I use the old connect syntax.

Comment: @drescherjm I am in a similar situation myself. What I do is make some hobby/test projects using the latest Qt version available, just to check the new functionalities and to get used to them.